# Assert attribute does not contain class in DalekJS

Tags: dalekjs

In DalekJS you can assert that an element has a class with

`test.assert.attr('#logOutButton', 'class').to.contain('ng-hide')`

Is it possible to somehow detect if an element does not have a class? When I write

`test.assert.attr('#logOutButton', 'class').to.not.contain('ng-hide')`

the test just ends without an error (just a warning that done() was not called). So this is maybe a bug and a feature request!?

Comment: Yep. This is currently not possible. Would you like to go over at github & post an issue there, so that we could track this properly?! Thanks.

Comment: Done (https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/issues/79) - thank you for the clarification :)